# Javascript - FileReader.target.result always return null

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, filereader

I have script in Javascript/JQuery, to read the image and convert it into text (base64). I have used FileReader to do it. and below is my code

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onloadend = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
    alert(fileLoadedEvent.result + "load event result");
    alert(fileLoadedEvent.target.result + "load event target result");
    var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64
    var newImage = document.createElement('img');
    newImage.src = srcData;
    base64_string = newImage.outerHTML;
    alert(base64_string + "base 64 code");
    alert(srcData + "srouce data  now");

}                       
fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
```

from the above code, fileLoadedEvent.target.result always returns null. so I'm unable to convert the image into text base64.

output for all alerts above

```
null load event result
```

`null load event target result`
`img base 64 code`

`null srouce data now`

Can anyone suggest me in fixing this issue

Comment: What are you passing as `fileToLoad`?

Comment: the event doesn't have `result` property, so the first one is normal being `null`. However `event.target.result` should contain the same as `this.result` being the result of the fileReader. `newImage.outerHTML` won't return a base64 string but the outer HTML of the image element (`<img src=""data:image/..."/>`)

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk, fileToLoad is the image name that I'm capturing via camera on real device

Comment: @Kaiido, can you please brief in detail with the code that you are supposing to explain in the comment.

Comment: Not sure to get this comment correctly, I was just pointing out that you are looking for things that don't exists so it's normal they return `null`. However, you should get `srcData` populated if you do pass a correct `fileToLoad` in the FileReader. An image name is not a good argument though, you need to pass either a `Blob` or a `File` object. Your problem certainly comes from here, so please add it in your question.